# how can i call fragment activity from negative button alertdialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

ExamplesActivity.class is fragment activity

LoginActivity.class is activity

in activity is work well but in fragment activity was stopped working ?
Please Help . .

```
  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("Logout Warning !!!")
    .setMessage("Apakah anda yakin keluar dari program ini?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            continue with delete
            Intent intent = new Intent(((Dialog) dialog).getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 

            Intent intent= new Intent(((Dialog) dialog).getContext() ,ExamplesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 


        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();
```

Comment: "stopped working" => **POST LOGCAT** ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this )

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you try to get the `Dialog context` while you get the `FragmentActivity` one.
Please give a try to the following code, and if it fails, please post your logcat.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
    .setTitle("Logout Warning !!!")
    .setMessage("Apakah anda yakin keluar dari program ini?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        { 
            continue with delete
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Intent intent= new Intent((getActivity(), ExamplesActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0); 
        }
    })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```